# Fetch values from a column named as 26-Nov-2014 in java from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, date

```
private static String fetchQuery = "select ? from tracker where serialNo = ?"

ps.setString(1,"26-Nov-2014");
ps.setString(2,"1");
```

I have also tried:

```
ps.setString(1,"'26-Nov-2014'");
ps.setString(2,"1");
```

But i did not get the answer....please someone help me out with this one.....

Comment: Could be just me but where is `ps` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a column name(s) after the select keyword in mysql, it seems the "26-Nov-2014" is a value not a column name.
But if the "26-Nov-2014" is your column name then try this.

```
private static String fetchQuery = "select \'?\' from tracker where serialNo = ?"
```

then

```
ps.setString(1,"26-Nov-2014");
ps.setString(2,"1");
```

If it doesn't work try to hardcode and test.

`private static String fetchQuery = "select \'26-Nov-2014\' from tracker where serialNo = 1"`

and comment out

```
// ps.setString(1,"26-Nov-2014");
// ps.setString(2,"1");
```

If it still doesn't work, try to run the query directly on database.